# como aumentar el valor de un div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Estoy simulando un reloj que esta a 0, en el cual el usuario puede modificar la hora, minutos y segundos.
he colocado 3 botones, el cambiar, selecciona si quiere aumentar la hora o disminuirla, así como los minutos, solo que no me funciona el aumentar minutos, me gustaría saber el por que no puedo aumentar los minutos.

Este es el reloj que estoy simulando 
[https://codepen.io/DanielHB/pen/RwwJMrP

Me gustaría saber como aumentar los minutos según la selección que el usuario elija.

```js
function pruebaH() {

  var h = 0;
  var m = 0;
  var s = 0;

  const hora = document.getElementById("hora");
  const minutos = document.getElementById("minutos");
  const segundos = document.getElementById("segundos");
  const sufijos = document.getElementById("sufijos");
  minutos.textContent = m;
  hora.textContent = h;
  segundos.textContent = s;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (s === 59) {
      s = -1; // Para que al final del bloque termine siendo 0
      m++;
      minutos.textContent = m;
    }
    if (m === 60) {
      m = 0;
      h++;
      hora.textContent = h;
      minutos.textContent = m;
    }
    if (h === 24) { /* le ponemos 12 y ya pasaria a pm  */
      h = 0;
      hora.textContent = h;
    }
    s++;
    segundos.textContent = s;
  }, 1000);

}

$("#cambiar").on('click', function() {
  var $lights = $(".container-flex").children();
  var numLights = $lights.length;
  var activeLight;
  for (var i = 0; i < numLights; i++) {

    if ($($lights[i]).hasClass("active")) {
      activeLight = i;
    }
  }

  // move active light to next item
  //activamos la luz al siguiente div
  $($lights[activeLight]).removeClass("active");
  nextActiveLight = (activeLight + 1) % numLights;
  $($lights[nextActiveLight]).addClass("active");
});

/* aumentamos el valor  */
var num = 0;
setValor();
$('#aumentar').click(function() {
  num++;
  setValor();
});

function setValor() {
  $('#hora').html(num);
}
/* disminuimos el valor */
$('#disminuir').click(function() {
  num--;
  setValor();
});
var num2 = 0;
setValor2();
$('#aumentar').click(function() {
  num2++;
  setValor2();

});
```

```css
.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

.container-flex div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-flex div {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.container-flex div.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="pruebaH()">

  <table border="1">

    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <th>Horas</th>
        <th>Minutos</th>
        <th>Segundos</th>
        <th>sufijo</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="container-flex" id="container2">

    <div class="" id="hora"></div>
    <div class="active" id="minutos"></div>
    <div class="" id="segundos"></div>

  </div>

  <button id="cambiar" class="cambiar">cambiar</button>
  <button id="aumentar">aumentar</button>
  <button id="disminuir">disminuir</button>
  <button id="guardar">Guardar</button>

  <script src="js/aumenta.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: En el `onClick()` de `#aumentar` y `#disminuir` llamás a la función `setValor()`, esa función está cambiando siempre el valor de `#hora`. Deberías seleccionar lo que tengas con la clase `.active`.

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes definido setValor2?

Comment: @azeós, tienes toda la razón, modifique esa parte y me funciona de maravilla.
creo que no es necesario el setValor2. bueno eso es lo que pienso.